# Avoid accessibility announcement of item number in recycler view

Tags: android, accessibility

I have list of different type of items in recyclerView and each one announce itself
I want to stop announcement of "showing item x of y" for each item

Is it possible? I need it for specific recyclerView
I read about AccessibilityDelegate but it doesn't seems to help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer, it's kind of hack, but it does what I need.

I used `AccessibilityDelegate` and override `inInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo` and set `roleDescription` like this:

```
            ViewCompat.setAccessibilityDelegate(recyclerView,
                object : AccessibilityDelegateCompat() {
                    override fun onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(v: View, info: AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat) {
                        super.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(v, info)
                        info.roleDescription = ""
                    }
                })
```

You can read more about it in here:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.AccessibilityDelegate